# tabMode изменять значение в зависимости от ориентации экрана

Tags: android, layout

Вопрос такой: Как правильно подставлять значение в tabMode, в зависимости от ориентации экрана.

**Вариант 1.**
Создать отдельный layout,  и положить его в layout-land. Создавать копию файла только из-за 1 параметра?! Это не укладывается в принципы полиморфизма.

**Вариант 2 (пока не рабочий).**
Для этого использую такое условие:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/TabLayoutMobile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="@{context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1 ? scrollable : fixed}" />
```

За невозможностью прокинуть константу, пришлось поставить грубое значение. В общем-то для меня дело принципа довести эту идею до конца (хороша она или не очень, но хочу понять как это сделать, и сделать правильно). Сейчас я получаю такую ошибку:

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: 
android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. scrollable is missing it
file:C:\Users\darkt\AndroidStudioProjects\PolykekSchedule\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_weekdays.xml
```

Почему-то нельзя поставить здесь условие, app:tabMode не принимает scrollable (может быть кто знает, пишите в коменты)

**Вариант 3.**
Изменять свойство программно. Но я хотел бы решить эту проблему на уровне layout-ов. Не хочу засорять код обработкой поворота экрана и установкой свойств!

Заключение: какой подход будет верным? Может у вас есть свое решение?